# How to load more than on language using #lang in Racket

Tags: python, c, racket

I'm trying to find a way to write a program by using more than one language models in Racket. For example, I wrote a c program in Racket like:

```
#lang c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a = 1;
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Then is it possible to put python code after above c code in Racket program so that the Racket program will looks like:

```
#lang c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a = 1;
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}

//Someting close the c language model

#lang python
def main():
    b = 2
    print "%d", %b
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have installed c and python language package in Racket and can write these languages in Racket singly.

Answer (score 2):

The language feature doesn't support writing multiple languages in the same file out of the box. However Alex Knauth has written an extension that allows you do what you want.

Check out the documentation here: http://docs.racket-lang.org/multi-file-lang/index.html

Comment: Thanks! I tried this extension and it does work. But how to let two program shares variables easily? Is storing variables into text file the only way to do that?

Comment: That depends on the languages. Some language provide a mechanism to export variables that can be used in other modules/files. Here the implementation of "#lang C" sadly doesn't (it basically writes a .c-file and invokes the standard C-compiler). Writing/reading to/from files is one way to go. Another is to look at pipes.

Comment: For "#lang racket", the language can import python programs like: "(require python) (py-impoort "pyfile1" as python-model)". Is there any similar way to import C program using "require"?

Comment: No. The Python language was implemented in such a way that it plays nicely with the Racket module system. The C one (due to the way it is implemented) does not.